# How to track data changes when deploying a SQL SSDT project

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

We upgrade out databases using SSDT DACPAC deployments. Developers work on the projects in VisualStudio 2015, modifying the schema where needed.

Developers also add Pre and Post deployment scripts to the projects. Some of these scripts ensure that certain tables always have the expected data in them. Others add, move, or mutate data as part of the platform upgrade.

We need to improve the output generated during database deployments so that, after a deployment, we have a human readable list of any `data` that changed as part of the deployment.

I'm currently considering two approaches. But neither seems ideal. They are:

> 1) Manually add logging to all Pre and Post scripts in the project. This is certainly an option. But it is not ideal because it complicates the upgrade scripts and is also likely to sometimes be missed or incorrectly done by developers. Since the goal is to detect unexpected data changes that occurred as part of the deployment, this uncertainty is a real bummer. A generic solution is preferable.
>
> 2) Here's my best stab at a generic solution: As part of the deployment process, enable SQL Change Data Capture for all user tables in the database. Then, at the end of the deployment, collect all captured changes and disable CDC. I've actually got this working. But the process of enabling CDC on all tables in the database takes a few minutes (one of our databases has 775 tables, it takes about 3 minutes to enable CDC on all of them). This approach also just feels very... heavy?

My question is. Is there a better way to achieve my goal of reliably generating a report of data that was changed as part of the database deployment, given that the deployment runs arbitrary Pre and Post deployment scripts?

If there does not seem to be a better way, I would appreciate feedback on option #2. Am I crazy for considering this?

Comment: I  am also working in an SSDT Datawarehouse projects and we use SVN to track changes and keep track of the current code, did you consider putting the whole project to an svn repository ?

Comment: Hi, @cybernetic87 Thanks for taking a look. Yes, we keep the project in SVN. What I'm interested in doing here is reporting on *data* that was changed at deployment time by the pre and post scripts in the project.

Comment: Can you work with the Devs to add PRINT statements to the pre/post script to explain what they're doing?  Maybe create a template for them to use/copy that includes the Start/stop time for each script as well as some quick note about what the script is doing?

Answer (score 0):

> Some of these scripts ensure that certain tables always have the expected data in them

First of all PreDeploy/PostDeploy scripts are not validated. I prefer to use them as launching point only, and do the actual work inside stored procedures.

So instead of writing:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tab1(id, col1, col2) VALUES (...,..., ...);
```

and inserting it on PostDeployscript, you could put:

```
EXEC dbo.Populate_Tab1;
```

and define stored procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Populate_Tab1
AS
BEGIN
   -- idempotent script, here by using MERGE
   WITH src(id, col1, col2,...) AS (
       SELECT 1, ..., ...  UNION ALL
       SELECT ...
   )
   MERGE dbo.tab1 trg
   USING src
     ON trg.id = src.id
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    ...
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT
     ...

END
```

Key point: stored procedure must be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

This way you are always sure that the table contain desired input data, and stored procedure is validated.

---

Similar approach is described by Kamil Nowinski:

> [Script and deploy the data for database from SSDT project](https://sqlplayer.net/2019/10/script-deploy-the-data-for-database-from-ssdt-project/)
>
> Advantages:
>
> The stored procedures are part of the database project.
>
> They will be validated and compiled, thus you avoid potential errors with uncontrolled code
>
> **The changes to the SP appears in output script only when something changes.**
>
> It’s easier to review the script before a run as it doesn’t contain unnecessary code
>
> In Post-deployment script – there is only one line of code which never is changed.